# Docker container communicating with private network/website

Tags: docker, containers, ip-address

I have a Docker container with a testing application in it.
This application needs to communicate with a website placed on a private network/server of my company. When I try to ping the website from inside the container, it tells me "Destination Host Unreachable" (ex. ping 172.17.11.x). I tried to ping one of our public websites and it can be reached.

So, how can my private website be seen from inside the container?

I found that in Docker you can create networks and run containers inside these newtworks, so maybe there is a way to assign a static IP (of my private network) to the container, so that it can see my private website... do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to ping the website from the host machine on which your docker container is running?

Comment: Do you mean if I try to ping from the cmd of my computer? Yeah I can, because I'm connected to the network of my company.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your docker container on the host network.

Use `--net host` in your docker run command.

Refer to [this](http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/) for a better understanding of Docker networking in host mode.